# why is my mysql date query not bring back all of the dates it should be

Tags: mysql, sql, date, sorting, datetime

this is a simplified version of what I was trying to search, but it is not working either.

```sql
SELECT * FROM WJ07LG4.appointments WHERE '2020-DECEMBER-5 20:30:00' <= END;
```

it returns the following please see the image under the link. I also linked the entire appointment table in an image. There are clearly two dates in the END Column that are also greater than the selected time, but only the one in April of 2021 is showing up. Really not understanding what I'm doing wrong here. I swear it was working before then it stopped all of a sudden. If you cant see the images, my problem is that the date that I have typed has 3 end column dates that are greater than it, but it is only bringing back one of the results it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using a valid MySQL date literal.  The following version is what you intended:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM WJ07LG4.appointments
WHERE END >= '2020-12-05 20:30:00';
```

Comment: Thank you. I had been working on it late at night and was tired. Guess a simple mistake like that slipped my mind.